# Extending Python ABCs with a protocol

Tags: python, python-typing

I'd like to create a new [typing protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544) that extends some common [base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#abstract-base-classes) (e.g., `Iterable`) with additional attributes. For example

```py
from typing import Iterable, Protocol

class IterableWithMethod(Iterable, Protocol):
    def method(self) -> None: pass


class ImplementsProtocol():
    def __iter__(self):
        ...
    
    def method(self):
        ...

def operatesOnProtocol(in: IterableWithMethod):
    ...
```

However, protocols [cannot subclass normal classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#protocols-subclassing-normal-classes). Is there a standard way to do this? Do protocol versions of the ABCs need to be added to the standard library?

Answer (score 0):

Given that `mypy` lists many of the abstract types exported by `typing` as ["predefined protocols"](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#predefined-protocols) and "Python protocols such as `Iterable` and `Sized`" are explicitly mentioned in the [PEP 544's rationale](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#rationale-and-goals) section, it should be fine to treat these built-in abstract classes as protocols.

For now, if [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) doesn't treat a built-in `ABC` like a protocol where it feels like it should, and the behavior is undocumented/undiscussed elsewhere, it may be worth raising as an issue until the docs for existing builtin protocol-like `ABC`s are better reconciled with the newer `Protocol` system.

More generally, until we have something like [pure-mixin classes](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/246), there won't be a pythonic way to go from normal class to protocol.